# How to start multiple datanode processes on standalone hadoop setup(pseudo-distributed)

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I have configured standalone hadoop setup on single VM running Ubuntu 13.03. After starting the hadoop processes using `start-all.sh`, `jps` command shows

```
775 DataNode
1053 JobTracker
962 SecondaryNameNode
1365 Jps
1246 TaskTracker
590 NameNode
```

As per my understanding Hadoop has started with 1 namenode and 1 datanode. I want to create multiple datanode processes i.e. multiple instances of datanode. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities how to install and configure Hadoop.

1. Local (standalone) Mode - it means all Hadoop components run in a signle Java process
2. Pseudo-Distributed Mode - Hadoop runs all its components (datanode, tastracker, jobtracker, namenode, ...) as separate Java processes. It servers as a simulation for fully distributed installation but it runs on local machine only.
3. Distributed Mode - fully distributed installation. Shortly without any details: Some machines play 'slave' role and contain Datanode+Tasktracker components and there is a server playing 'master' role and contains Namenode+JobTracker.

Back to your queastion, if you would like to run Hadoop on single machine, you have the first two options. It is impossible to run it in fully distributed mode on a single node. Maybe you can do do a workaround, but it is nonsence from basic point of view. Hadoop was designed as a distributed system, the possibility to run it on a single machine serves IMHO for debug/trial purposes only.

For more details follow [Hadoop documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation). I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Why couldn't one use Hadoop in fully distributed mode on a single machine if the machine had many cores and the task involved big data?